# Indian Citizen applying for Australian Visitor Visa from USA

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, australia

I'm currently working in the US on an L1B visa, and my visa is expiring on November 2019. I'm planning to visit Australia on a Tourist/Visit visa during December to visit my friends. I'm planning to fly from India to Australia during that time. I have the following queries. I appreciate your help in advance.

1. Can I apply online in the US and select the country of residence as the US?
2. Since my visa is expiring in November, the recommended document says valid visa and right to return. But I'm planning to travel from India only. So will selecting the current location as the US cause any problem?
3. I have recently moved, so my payslips and bank account are still in India. Can I show them as proof of funds?
4. How long will it take to process the visitor visa?

Update:
OP applied selecting India as the country of residence and was granted the visa.

Finally, I travelled from US to Australia directly in December 2019 when my US visa was filed for extension. No problem on flights or Australia immigration with my visitor visa. Then returned to India to get it stamped again and came back to US.

Comment: Will you be leaving the US in or before November, without plans to return?  If your visa is expiring, but you're going to renew it, and you are maintaining an apartment or other home in the US, then it may well be that you *should* say that you reside in the US.  If you've applied already and have some insight from your experience, could you either post a comment on the accepted answer or add an answer of your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may apply for the visa online but should not select the US as your country of residence (unless you are granted a relevant US visa).

I don't think it matters where your bank and pay documents are from as long as they show your ability to support yourself for the duration of your visit.

At the time of writing processing times are:

75% of applications processed within 16 days
90% of applications processed within 26 days.

See https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas#Overview

Comment: Is residence for this purpose is the same as being a "lawful permanent resident", rather then where the person is actually living? L1B is a dual intent visa.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan good question. It may not need to be permanent residency (the OP should clarify that with Australian immigration) but if the visa is expiring before the trip to Oz I don't think the OP can claim to be living in the US.

Comment: Chose residing as India and got the Visa.

Comment: "if the visa is expiring before the trip to Oz I don't think the OP can claim to be living in the US": US visa validity has nothing to do with whether one's presence in the US is lawful.  If someone arrives with an L-1B visa that expires 6 months after entering but is granted a 3-year period of admission and then remains in the US for 3 years, that person is certainly residing in the US even after the visa expires.

Comment: @phoog lawful presence doesn't necessarily mean you live there either. OP mentioned the expiring visa, so I took that to mean they would need to renew.

Comment: There is only a need to renew the visa if the person plans to leave and re-enter the US, which wasn't the case here.